# how to DEBUG exe file (former asm) on windows 7

Tags: assembly

how do i open DEBUG in dosbox for an exe file on win7 
(assembly file)
traied td not work 
traied DEBUG get to a new line with no option to enter my file name 
traied DEBUG  got a new line that start with -

hoe do i open the file?

Comment: Your question is a bit difficult to parse, but the command for starting `debug` for an executable named `foo.exe` is supposed to be `debug foo.exe`.

Comment: i did this (debug base.exe) and all i got is a new line that start with a - when i traied to enter base.exe again i got an error

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to assemble 16-bit asm code using NASM, then debug it in Linux, before making an executable in DOSBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22270915/how-to-assemble-16-bit-asm-code-using-nasm-then-debug-it-in-linux-before-makin)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not tutorial site and it does not replace the golden [RTFM](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=RTFM) rule. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting another question

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/9lacyb.jpg this is the screen shut

Comment: Is it a DOS executable or a Windows one? Did you build it?

Comment: its DOS (dosbox) and yes i did build it (first i did asm file then i make it exe throu dosbox and now im stack...

Answer (score 2):

As Michael said, to debug a program, you use `debug foo.exe`.

Printing a '-' is what the debugger does to show that it is ready to accept a debugging command.  Try entering '?' to see the list of available debugging commands.  Or you can use 't' to start single-stepping thru the program.  You can also visit https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722863.aspx for a more detailed explanation of the available commands.

Be aware that the dos 'debug' program is a **very** simple debugger.  If you are used to a full-screen, multiple-window, source code debugger, you are going to be really disappointed.  'debug' is more limited than most other debuggers, and harder to learn.

If you are going to take the time to learn how to use a debugger, 'debug' wouldn't normally be the one I recommend.

Comment: its supost to open some blue screan with all the hex value of my program
how do i grt to this screan? 
i a very beginner so maybe its somw nunsens i forgat to add or something like this
please take a look on the pecture and tell me where i did run or how to get to the right screen 
http://postimg.org/image/4tlnrovr

Comment: The dos debug does not open "some blue screen."  It's black and white.  For a sample screenshot of dos debug, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debug_%28command%29  Perhaps you are thinking of some other debugger?  If you want to use dos debug to see your code along with a hex representation, try entering 'u' as a command.  Your 'postimg.org' link is prompting me to login and does not show me an image.

Comment: @H_meir _Insight Debugger, real-mode DOS 16-bit debugger developed by Victor Gamayunov, Sergey Pimenov, Oleg O. Chukaev, Dmitry Vodyannikov_ opens **green** screen. Check http://www.freedos.org/software/?prog=insight if you're interested. Borland's Turbo Debugger opened **blue** screen (http://www.danielsays.com/ss-gallery-dos-turbo-debugger-20.html)